# Riemann's theorem on removable singularities and its implication

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

The theorem I'm working with is the following:

Let $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ be an open set, $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ a holomorphic function, $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ an isolated singularity of $f$.

Then the following are equivalent:

1. $z_0$ is a removable singularity
2. $\lim_{z\to z_0} f(z)$ exists (i.e. $\in \mathbb{C}$)
3. $\lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0)f(z) = 0$

Now there's a remark in my notes that says:

The implication 3. ⇒ 2. implies also, that there does not exist a holomorphic function $f:\text{B}(0,1)\backslash\{0\} \to \mathbb{C}$ such that there exists a $L \geq 1$ with
$$
\frac{1}{L}|z|^{-\frac{1}{2}} \leq |f(z)| \leq L|z|^{-\frac{1}{2}}
$$

This is not true in $\mathbb{R}$, for example this $f$ fulfils the inequality above:
$$
f\left( x\right) =\begin{cases}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}},x >0\\
-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{-x}},x <0\end{cases}
$$

**My question is:** I don't see how 3. ⇒ 2. implies the non-existence of such a function in $\mathbb{C}$. Does anyone care to explain this to me?

Comment: a function $\frac{1}{L}|z|^{-\frac{1}{2}} \leq |f(z)| \leq L|z|^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ satisfies $3$ but not $2$ and that is not possible by the implication above

Comment: @Conrad Thank you for your response. I figured it out now.

Comment: Happy to be of help

Comment: The restrictions of being holomorphic on $B(0,1)\setminus\{0\}$ is much stronger than being differentiable on $[-1,1]\setminus\{0\}$. For one thing $B(0,1)\setminus\{0\}$ is connected, whereas $[-1,1]\setminus\{0\}$ is not. For another, being differentiable on an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ implies infinite differentiability, which is not the case for a function differentiable on an open set of $\mathbb{R}$.